# When firing responsive jQuery functions the function doesn't stop firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have a problem with responsively firing certain jQuery / JavaScript functions. I have checked out the following article: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries which describes how to only fire a JavaScript / jQuery function at a certain screen resolution, but by using the same resolution as with the CSS media queries (for example between a width of 0px up to 767px). This is the code that I use:
*jQuery / JavaScript:*

```
// Function to open / close modal
function modal() {

    $(".activator").click(function() {
        $('.modal-wrapper').show();
    });

    $(".modal-overlay").click(function() {
        $('.modal-wrapper').hide();
    });
    $(".modal-close-button").click(function() {
        $('.modal-wrapper').hide();
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) $('.modal-wrapper').hide(); // remove modal on escape press
    });

}

// Launch modal function responsively
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

function checkSize() {
    if ($(".mytext").css("display") == "none") {
        modal();
    }
}
```

*CSS used:*

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .mytext {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Please see my full modal function on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMaoLP).

I use the jQuery code above for implementing my modal window function. I want this modal function to only work and open a modal on desktops, not on small resolutions (< 767 px). The **problem** which I'm facing however is that the jQuery solution from the article above does work, but once I open my HTML page on a desktop and *resize* the window to a phone screen resolution the modal function still fires and thus the modal window still open, which I want to stop on mobile resolutions (< 767px). The modal function however doesn't fire if I load the HTML page on a phone resolution at first, so then it does work in the way I meant it to work.
I think it has to do with the modal function **still running** once I resize it from a desktop resolution towards a phone resolution. Is there a way I can made it work so that the modal function stops firing if I resize from a desktop resolution towards a phone resolution without refreshing the page?

Comment: Your mytext-element will be hidden (display = none) when the screen size is ***bigger*** than 767. So yes, it will fire if you open the page on "desktop", the modal-function will execute immediately, nothing to do with resizing.

Comment: @Esko Yes, I know. But what I want is to fire the modal function when I open the web page at a desktop resolution first, and then once I resize the browser window to something with a smaller width than 767px I want the modal function to stop firing, so that the modal doesn't launch anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you go all this length not to attach a few eventhandlers on desktop, they will not be fired if the elements are hidden anyway? But if you want you can always unbind the eventhandlers if the screen has been resized (else in checksize-method). If that is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm.. you assign an event handler to the activator, but you don't remove it on resize of the "desktop". If you move or copy the condition from the CheckSize function:

```
if ($(".mytext").css("display") == "none")
```

To the first modal event:

```
$(".activator").click(function()  {
if ($(".mytext").css("display") == "none")           $('.modal- 
wrapper').show();
});
```

It would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now changed the script and it works flawlessly ;-)